# Why isn't the screen rebuild in flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

[image]

I split the screen into 2 parts, the upper part to change the state when each time I clicked, the bottom part is a list, when the state is loaded, I try to add an event to sort, it still works but the screen don't rebuild again

My code here
Hope everyone can help! Thank

widget

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => referrerBloc,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              flag1(referrerBloc.add(ReferrerSortEvent)), 
              flag2(referrerBloc.add(ReferrerSortEvent)), 
              flag3(referrerBloc.add(ReferrerSortEvent)),
              BlocBuilder<ReferrerBloc, ReferrerState>(
                builder: (__, state) {
                  if (state is ReferrerLoadingState) {
                    referrerBloc.add(ReferrerLoadedEvent());
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else if (state is ReferrerLoadedState) {
                    final listReferrer = state.listReferrer;
                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: listReferrer.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 16,
                              ),
                              child: itemUser(listReferrer.elementAt(index)),
                            );
                          },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Error!',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

My code here Hope everyone can help! Thank
My code here Hope everyone can help! Thank
event

```
part of 'referrer_bloc.dart';

abstract class ReferrerEvent extends Equatable {
  const ReferrerEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ReferrerLoadingEvent extends ReferrerEvent {}

class ReferrerLoadedEvent extends ReferrerEvent {}

class ReferrerSortEvent extends ReferrerEvent {
  const ReferrerSortEvent({required this.flag, required this.time});
  final int flag;
  final int time;
}

class ReferrerErrorEvent  extends ReferrerEvent {}
```

My code here Hope everyone can help! Thank
My code here Hope everyone can help! Thank
state

```
part of 'referrer_bloc.dart';

abstract class ReferrerState extends Equatable {
  const ReferrerState();
}

class ReferrerLoadingState extends ReferrerState {
  const ReferrerLoadingState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ReferrerLoadedState extends ReferrerState {

  const ReferrerLoadedState({required this.listReferrer});
  final List<ItemReferrer> listReferrer;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [listReferrer];
}
```

My code here Hope everyone can help! Thank
My code here Hope everyone can help! Thank
bloc

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:helloapp/referrer/models/item_referrer.dart';

part 'referrer_event.dart';
part 'referrer_state.dart';

class ReferrerBloc extends Bloc<ReferrerEvent, ReferrerState> {

  ReferrerBloc() : super(const ReferrerLoadingState()) {
    on<ReferrerEvent>((event, emit) {

    });
    on<ReferrerLoadedEvent>((event, emit) {
      final listUser = [
        Item1,
       ......
      ];
      emit(ReferrerLoadedState(listReferrer: listUser));
    });
    
    on<ReferrerSortEvent>((event, emit) {
      print(event.flag);
      final listUser = [
        Item1, 
        ........
      ];
      final List<ItemReferrer> listResult = [];
      if (event.flag == 0) {
        listUser.forEach(listResult.add);
      } else if (event.flag == 1) {
        listUser.forEach((element) {
          if (element.flag == 1) {
            listResult.add(element);
          }
        });
      }
      emit(ReferrerLoadedState(listReferrer: listResult));
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the behaviour you want vs what you are achieving?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabBar instead of Column.

Here's the official link of Flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs

Comment: I want to practice with bloc @Cavin Macwan

Comment: Yeah sure you can use BLoC but the layout you are to implement is a type of Tabbar so you can practice in that layout too with better accuracy because in real projects you will have to use TabBar with BLoC in this scenario.